# How does JVM pick an overriding method in below scenarios?

Tags: java, jvm, overriding

```
class Foo {
    public void foo(Collection arg) {
        System.out.println("Bonjour");
        }
    public void foo(List arg) {
        System.out.println("Ola");
        }
    public void foo(ArrayList arg) {
        System.out.println("ArrayList");
        }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    
    
    public void foo(List arg) {
        System.out.println("Ola bar");
        }
    public void foo(ArrayList arg) {
        System.out.println("ArrayList bar");
        }
}
public class om2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        Foo f2 = new Bar();
        Bar b1 = new Bar();
        List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
        
        f1.foo(c);
        f2.foo(c);
        b1.foo(c);
    

    }
```

Output : Ola.
Ola Bar.
Ola Bar.

Can any one explain how this output came, I thought the compiler would pick up

```
f1.foo(c) -> ArrayList method
f2.foo(c) -> ArrayList method
b1.foo(c) -> ArrayList method
```

As we have exact matching type array list would be ideal, right? but I see different output

Comment: `c` is declared as `List`, so the compiler uses that type to pick the method.

Comment: Don´t confuse *overriding* and *overloading*. An overriding method is selected based on the actual (runtime) *receiver* type, that is the type of the object resulting from evaluating the expression to the left of the `.`. Which of an overloaded method is selected, depends on the *compile-time type(s)* of the parameter(s). As Olivier said, the compile-time type of the parameter is `List`. If you need a runtime selection of a method based on an actual parameter object, look for the Visitor Pattern.

Comment: Thank you to Oliver and Holger.
a.) So above is example of overloading or overriding, sorry I am just confused. Kindly help
b.) I understand, based on reference types methods gets called at compile but at  run time, based on object it gets called. So I though here array list method would be picked

Comment: Having three methods, `foo(Collection)`, `foo(List)`, and `foo(ArrayList)`, is *overloading*. The right method to invoke, will be selected at compile-time, based on the compile-time types, i.e. `foo(List)` will be invoked due to `c`’s type. Having a method `foo(List)` in class `Bar` matching a declaration in superclass `Foo`, is *overriding*. Whether `Foo`’s `foo(List)` or `Bar`’s `foo(List)` method is invoked, depends on the actual runtime type of the object. So `f2.foo(c)` invokes `Bar`’s `foo(List)` method because the object’s actual type is `Bar`, even though `f2`’s declared type is `Foo`.